# Is there a way to compute code coverage metric through selenium tests in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir

I know code coverage is meant to be defined by the no. of unit test cases written for that specific product but Is there a way, that can be calculated through Selenium tests? Application that I've the selenium tests for, is written on Ruby on Rails and the UI automation cases are written on Ruby with Selenium libraries. I want to know, when I run my regression suite, what is the percentage of code coverage it actually covers in the main product.

Comment: Selenium tag is enough to cover the selenium questions. I added WATIR tag because people from WATIR maintains the Ruby Selenium Binding.

Comment: Have you tried with Simplecov or Codecov gems? you should get the codecoverage for the ruby code that's stressed by your selenium tests.

Comment: @arieljuod I have used those two gems previously but those are meant to compute the code coverage based on the unit test(backend - controllers & models) cases that's written over the application itself. Here I'm asking if there's a way that i can get the code coverage through the selenium tests.

Comment: Selenium has no provisions for calculating code coverage.  Given it runs on the browser, even if it did, it would only be aware of JS code executing on the browser, and has no instrumentation of the web server.
You will need to use third party tools to monitor the code being executed.   Look for tools designed to do coverage analysis during “end to end testing”

Comment: @EsakiRaja Simplecov's readme tells you how to use it with selenium https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov `When testing a server process (e.g. a JSON API endpoint) via a separate test process (e.g. when using Selenium) where you want to see all code executed by the rails server, and not just code executed in your actual test files, you need to require SimpleCov in the server process.`